# Is there an equivalent for TStringGrid::SetEditText in FMX?

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, c++builder-10.3-rio

I'm trying to live update some values with the values that the users enters in the grid, however i can't find a solution in FMX, i found SetEditText but it's only VCL...

Comment: I don't have version 10.3-Rio, but in 10.1 Berlin there is an event `OnEditingDone`. It fires when focus moves away from the currently edited cell (iow when the in-place editor loses focus). I believe this would work in 10.3 also. In version XE7, it fires for every entered character.

Comment: That's what i'm using right now but i want something that triggers each time the user enters a character, without leaving the cell.